# Redirect_uri_mismatch doesnt work

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

Hello,
i have issues with redirect URI, when i want to log in google oauth2, it doesnt redirect me and gimme Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

```
access_type=online
approval_prompt=auto
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
response_type=code
redirect_uri=http://www.meetingroomapp.com/dashboard/oauth2callback.php
state=
client_id=825645938882-ftcv0fuojum9078uht1n8hpgbvp9ej3f.apps.googleusercont
```

There is code in index.php

```
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

SOME CODE HERE 

} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://www.meetingroomapp.com/dashboard/oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

There is code in oauth2callback.php

```
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secret.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://www.meetingroomapp.com/dashboard/');
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");

if (! isset($_GET['code'])) { //přesměrování na google server
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect_uri = 'http://www.meetingroomapp.com/dashboard/';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

There is secret JSON

```
{"installed":{"client_id":"**ID**","project_id":"meetinroomapp","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"**SECRET**","redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://www.meetingroomapp.com/dashboard/"]}}
```

In Google developer console i have set http://www.meetingroomapp.com/dashboard/ as homepage

Comment: what ever the redirect uri is in the error message you need to set the redirect uri to that in Google Developers console. The redirect uri must match the where you are sending it from.

Answer (score 1):

redirect mismatch happens when the redirect uri you specified  in you request doesnt match the one you specified in google developer console.so check if the the redirect uri you specfied in google developer console is  http://www.meetingroomapp.com/dashboard/oauth2callback.php